# Segmentation fault in char array

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve anagram problem from https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/anagram/0. When I try in my computer with custom inputs, it works fine. But when I try it in the above link, it throws segmentation fault. What am I doing here wrong? Thanks in advance.

My code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int checkAnagram(char a[],char b[])
{
  int i,x=0;
  int n = strlen(a);
  int m = strlen(b);

  if(n != m)
    return -1;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x^=a[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x^=b[i];
  }

  return x;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int t;    //No of testcases
  char a[100],b[100];
  scanf("%d", &t);
  while(t--)
  {
    scanf("%s", a);
    scanf("%s", b);
    checkAnagram(a,b) == 0?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

PS - Please try it in the above link. I cant possibly know all the testcases they pass including the hidden ones.

Comment: Is b and a always same size?

Comment: Are you guaranteed your input is no more than 100 characters?  Also, are you using C or C++?  The code as is is C, besides the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`

Comment: When posting questions from sites such as the one you mentioned, you should remove the input routines, and instead hard-code the sample data into the program.  No one here is going to keep typing in input each and every time the program is run.  [This is an example of a better post](https://www.ideone.com/LpQcD9).

Comment: Sorry. I posted a little older code here.I used scanf and printf since they are a bit faster than cin and cout

Comment: I posted this way coz hard-coded way you say works fine when I execute it in my machine.

Comment: @SilamArasu You don't understand -- are we to guess what input doesn't work?  That is *your* job to provide to us the input that doesn't work, and when you find it, hard-code that in your post.  Just posting verbatim all of that input stuff with `t` and `scanf` is not required to answer your question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Bro, They passes testcases of different sizes and that includes hidden testcases too. So Idk with what input they execute the code

Comment: In your code, the words are stored in two arrays declared as `char a[100],b[100];`, but the constraint for the strings in problem description is 1 ≤ |s| ≤ 10^16.

Comment: Since the strings can be such long lengths, even `strlen` may not work.  Time to think of another way of doing this.

Comment: First, why not try using a simple array of 26 integers, and add 1 to the array slot that corresponds to the letter?  Then you would have two arrays and you just compare them for equality.  This exclusive-or thing you're doing is a testament of trying to be too fancy just for the sake of it, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
void checkAnagram(char a[],char b[])
{
  int n1 = strlen(a);
  int n2 = strlen(b);
  if (n1 != n2) {
    printf("NO\n");
    return;
  }
  int x=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    x^=a[i];
    x^=b[i];
  }
  x == 0?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
}
```

EDIT (explanation):
your arrays might differ in size. Since two different sized arrays can't be anagrams of each other, we first check for it and bail out, if size differs.

Note, that even without this logical requirement you still need to check for arrays size. You access both arrays at index `i`, so you need to make sure **both** arrays are at least that size.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: Thanks man. I have changed the code. But still the error persists.

Comment: Code works on my computer. What error is happening on your side? Maybe you're entering long texts? Maximum is 99 characters, as your array is 100 size.

Comment: Code works fine in my side too. But it doesn't pass all the testcases that is in https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/anagram/0 for some reason.

Comment: Because it's not enough (even tho idea is clever). Consider for example texts "azz" and "ayy". Since you've used xor operator, two exactly the same letters cancel each other. So i "azz" will reduce to "a" and "ayy" will also reduce to "a". But "azz" ain't an anagram of "ayy".

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Heck! I didn't even think that way. Thanks for pointing out.